# Making categorized symbols mutually exclusive using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, symbology

[image: Categorized Symbols]

I am wondering if there is a way in PyQGIS to automate the process of selecting/deselecting the check marks for each categorized symbol in the included picture. I am writing a plugin and would like to be able to have the option of viewing one of the symbols at a time instead of seeing all of them at once.

Answer (score 4):

This code snippet should do the work. The key is to use `updateCategoryRenderState()`, which should be `True` for checked values, and `False` for unchecked ones.

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
renderer = layer.renderer()

value = "100001"
for i, cat in enumerate(renderer.categories()):
    renderer.updateCategoryRenderState(i, cat.value() == value)

layer.setRenderer(renderer)
iface.layerTreeView().refreshLayerSymbology(layer.id())
layer.triggerRepaint()
```